# Block specific url for specific country via .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm looking to achieve blocking specific urls for 1 specific country via .htaccess. What I got so far is a block to the entire site, but what I'm looking is to block a specific url of the site. Here is what I got.

```
<Limit GET POST>
order allow,deny
deny from 2.20.179.0/24
deny from 2.20.185.0/24
deny from 2.22.230.0/24
deny from 2.136.0.0/15
deny from 2.138.0.0/15
allow from all
</Limit>
```

Having that, how could I block the url http://domain.com/en/profiles/kasper, for that specific IP ranges / country? What is the right way to include that url in the htaccess?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mod_rewrite` if you are in htaccess and want to block URLs for certain IPs:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^2\.20\.(179|185)\.(\d|1\d|2[0-4])$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^2\.22\.230\.(\d|1\d|2[0-4])$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^2\.(136|138)\.0\.0$
RewriteRule ^en/profiles/kasper(/.*)$ - [F,NC]
```